# What type does Excel Worksheet.Usedrange return

Tags: c#, excel, c#-4.0, office-interop

I am converting an app from vba to C#. It's going slowly. Here's my first challenge...

In vba, I can assign an Excel range to a vba two-dimensional array:

```
Dim strSheetArray as Variant
strSheetArray = xlSH.UsedRange
...
debug.print strSheetArray[1,2]     'etc.
```

When I convert to C#, the "UsedRange" property seems to return an object. I can't seem to use that object like an array, getting code-time errors. So, how do I refer to the returned object so I can iterate through it?

And, as long as I'm at it, the cells have no type, so how do I use them (some are number, others are text, etc.) It was pretty easy in vba....

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Should have noted, I'm using Office Interop. My vba program used it as well, from Access2007....

Comment: You're not using "Set" when assigning `strSheetArray`, so what you're actually getting is the return value for the default property of `Range`, which is `Value`. Same as calling `strSheetArray = xlSH.UsedRange.Value`   See here for how to read to an array in C#, which is what i think you're after:  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pl/exceldev/thread/808ec772-cf5b-4589-a8ec-7a01683f7537

Answer (score 2):

It returns a Range Interface. You can read more about it [at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range%28v=office.11%29.aspx).

> And, as long as I'm at it, the cells have no type, so how do I use them (some are number, others are text, etc.) It was pretty easy in vba....

The cells do have a type, but they are just objects.You will have to cast to what you want it to be. So if the cell is text, you will have to do something like:

```
(string)xlSheet.Cells[row,col].Value2
```

or

```
xlSheet.Cells[row,col].Value2.ToString();
```

You would have to cast to a numeric type as well if you knew they were numbers.

---

Edit based comments:

So if you want to get the used range you would do this:

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

Excel.Range range = xlSheet.UsedRange;
```

This will give you everything from the worksheet (I used the variable xlSheet, which is Excel.Worksheet).

Now we can iterate over this by doing:

```
int rows = range.Rows.Count;
int cols = range.Columns.Count;

for(int r=1; r <= rows; r++)
{
    for(int c=1; c <= cols; c++)
    {
        Console.Write(range.Cells[r,c].Value2.ToString());
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

This will iterate over the range and basically replicate what is in your spreadsheet in the console window. I hope this helps. I also wrote a blog post on reading Excel spreadsheets using C# which you can read [here](http://dontbreakthebuild.com/2011/01/30/excel-and-c-interop-with-net-4-how-to-read-data-from-excel/) if you want.

Comment: I mis-stated the question(s). I want to return the entire range into a C# multidimensional array so I avoid hundreds of trips to the Interop, which are quite slow. Then, I want to work entirely with the array.
  I understand how to use the Interop, but assigning the range to an object in C# leaves me with (apprently, from what I've been reading), an object of type "System.Object[,]". Now what do I do. Intellisense won't let me assign to a variable of type "Object[,]".

Comment: @JatinKhurana is it returning a value at all or just erring out? I haven't tried this on merged cells before.

Comment: @JEtti............ yesterday I have worked a lot on it.......... When we merged cells in excel, it's merged the cells only for display but cells exist for a program. Now only one cell out of merged cells has data and other cells have no data.One important thing, When cell has no data, range.Cells[r,c].Value2 returns null. So when u call ToString on that. NullPointer Exception. So after for loop check whether range.Cells[r,c].Value2 is null or not......... I was facing this issue for last 4 days but now I have resolved it........... I think it will help you